# get only tweets which contains desired word in Twitter 4J

Tags: apache-storm, twitter4j, twitter-streaming-api

```
// create the twitter stream factory with the config
TwitterStreamFactory fact =
    new TwitterStreamFactory(config.build());

// get an instance of twitter stream
twitterStream = fact.getInstance();

FilterQuery tweetFilterQuery = new FilterQuery(); // See
tweetFilterQuery.locations(new double[][]{new double[]   {-124.848974,24.396308},
                new double[]{-66.885444,49.384358
                }});
tweetFilterQuery.language(new String[]{"en"});
tweetFilterQuery.track(new String[]{"sony", "apple" });

// provide the handler for twitter stream
twitterStream.addListener(new TweetListener());

twitterStream.filter(tweetFilterQuery);

// start the sampling of tweets
//twitterStream.sample();
```

In twitter spout I only want the tweets which have words apple or sony, I have tried tweetFilterQuery.track(). I need only tweets which contains sony and apple words.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please have a look at some helpful tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - asking a good question improves your chances of getting an answer. In your specific case, you also need to explain what you expect the results to be and what you are currently getting- also indicate if there are any errors. This will be more helpful than posting a code and say "it is not working".

Comment: Thank you very much for suggestion @ishmaelMakitla

Comment: What are you getting? I have the feeling that the location is limiting your results

Comment: I am getting all the tweets and I used location because I want tweets only for US. I am using d3 to show it on the map @FeanDoe

Comment: Might better to remove the tag 'apache' and 'apache-storm' since your question is just about twitter streaming api issue.